# Call one jquery plugin in the callback of another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use these two jquery plugins together a type watch (https://github.com/dennyferra/TypeWatch) and toaster (http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Bootstrap-Based-Toast-Notification-Plugin-toaster.html).

Howerver when I exchange the line

```
 callback: function (value) { alert('TypeWatch callback: (' + this.type + ') ' + value); }
```

by

```
callback: function (value) {
    $.toaster({ priority : 'success', title : 'Saved', message : '' }); }
```

it shows nothing. How can I integrate these two plugins?
Here is the whole script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    callback: function (value) {
    $.toaster({ priority : 'success', title : 'Saved', message : '' }); },
    wait: 750,
    highlight: true,
    captureLength: 2
}
$("#content").typeWatch( options );
</script>
```

Thanks in advanced.

Alex

Comment: This first one is wrong as you are using the `alert` as a parameter to the `toaster` method. It will show the alert but not for the reasons you think. The second one is the correct. Have you included the `toaster` script file ? Is bootstrap used as it is a requirement.

Comment: I have included the toaster script file. I believe the scope I'm using is wrong. The callback function might not know what is $.toaster. Am I correct?

Comment: Not really. toaster as noted by `$.` is a plugin to jquery. This means that it is always available assuming you are not using multiple jquery versions in your page. If you have a live version where the problem is present it would be helpful.

Comment: I put it here https://jsfiddle.net/alexlopespereira/09oamd1j/17/. But I could not make the typewatch work in jsfiddle (it works on my local pc). Do you know what I've done wrong?